# Can I play Event Cards before I place Trogs?

Tags: claustrophobia

Can the card Terror be used before you place Trogs, if you draw the Event Card that turn? It says it can be played during the Threat phase, but when is the Threat Phase in relation to rolling dice, placing dice, drawing Event Cards, summoning Demons/Trogs, and moving/attacking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play **Terror** before or after summoning Troglodytes, or at any other point during the Threat Phase.

The **Threat Phase** is broken up into two steps. Event Cards that can be played "during the Threat Phase," can be played before or after either step (but not in-between rolling dice and resolving their effects). Drawing Event Cards is an effect of resolving **Dark Destiny**. The Demon Player's Action Phase is when Trogs and Demons move and attack, it follows the Threat Phase.

- Roll Dice of Destiny

  1) Roll 3d6 usually.

  2) Place Dice on Destiny Squares.

  3) Immediately resolve effects of Destiny Squares.
- Place Troglodytes and Demons

From the [Official Rules](http://www.claustrophobia-theboardgame.com/fr/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/CLAUSTRO_RULEBOOK_US_LR_LR.pdf):

> **Threat Phase**
>
> During this phase, the Demon player will bring the Demons and Troglodytes into play, improve their abilities and draw Event cards.
>
> **Demon Player's Action Phase**
>
> During this phase, the Demon player’s Troglodytes and Demons will move and fight.
>
> **Event Cards**
>
> The Dark Destiny result of the Board of Destiny allows the Demon player to draw an Event card. This card can be kept in his hand or **used at the time indicated** in its description (and must then be discarded).The Demon player can keep as many Event cards in his hand as he wishes.